# I want a VBA coding for access that will delete records from multiple table with a condition

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need some VBA code for access that will delete records from multiple table with a condition where the bill number of the record equals to the bill number in the form. My problem is that I have given space for the table name i.e bill subject, bill footer and do not have time to change the table name in all the coding. Please help me.

Comment: Provide additional info: Specific table names, field names, conditions, and any other relevant information. Please remember that we can't see what you're seeing, so you have to tell us. Also, if you have attempted any solutions, post them. Please read: ["How to ask"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

for SQL, encapsulate table or column names with [brackets] if they have spaces

if you're trying to get to the form's col and it has spaces, use the recordset object.

```
docmd.runsql "DELETE * FROM [bill subject] where billno = me.recordset.fields("bill no").value
```